# How to control the number of CPUs used by R?

Tags: r

I'm using [the R package crossmatch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crossmatch/index.html) that itself relies on some other R packages (   survival, nbpMatching, MASS) and that in turn import a wide range of more dependencies.
The crossmatch package implements a statistical test on a (potentially) large matrix, that I need to compute very often (within an MCMC algorithm). I've written the following wrapper that computes some preprocessing steps before the actual test is computed (which is the `crossmatchtest()` in the last line):

```
# wrapper function to directly call the crossmatch test with a single matrix
# first column of the matrix must be a binary group indicator, following columns are observations
# code is modified from the documentation of the crossmatch package
crossmatchdata <- function(dat) {

  # the grouping variable should be in the first column
  z = dat[,1]
  X = subset(dat, select = -1)

  ## Rank based Mahalanobis distance between each pair:
  # X <- as.matrix(X)
  n <- dim(X)[1]
  k <- dim(X)[2]

  for (j in 1:k) {
    X[, j] <- rank(X[, j])
  }

  cv <- cov(X)
  vuntied <- var(1:n)
  rat <- sqrt(vuntied / diag(cv))

  cv <- diag(rat) %*% cv %*% diag(rat)
  out <- matrix(NA, n, n)

  icov <- ginv(cv)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    out[i, ] <- mahalanobis(X, X[i, ], icov, inverted = TRUE)
  }

  dis <- out

  ## The cross-match test:
  return(crossmatchtest(z, dis))
}
```

I've noticed that if the matrix is rather small, this test will only use one CPU:

```
library(MASS)
library(crossmatch)
source("theCodeFromAbove.R")
# create a dummy matrix
m = cbind(c(rep(0, 100), rep(1, 100)))
m = cbind(m, (matrix(runif(100), ncol=10, nrow=20, byrow=T)))
while(TRUE) { crossmatchdata(m) }
```

as monitored via `htop`. However, if I'm increasing this matrix, R will use as many cores as are available (at least it looks like this):

```
# create a dummy matrix
m = cbind(c(rep(0, 1000), rep(1, 1000)))
m = cbind(m, (matrix(runif(100000), ncol=1000, nrow=2000, byrow=T)))
while(TRUE) { crossmatchdata(m) }
```

I'm fine with this parallelization in general but I would like to be able to manually control the number of cores the R process is using. I've tried `options(mc.cores = 4)` without success.

Is there any other variable I could set? Or what's the best way of finding the package that's responsible for the use of more than one core?

Comment: First you need to tell us which part of your code is parallelized. Any of the functions you use? Or is the parallelization within the BLAS linked to R? Vanilla (base) R is not parallelized.

Comment: That's the point of my question: I did not parallelize any code, it just happens automagically somewhere deep in the dependencies and I don't know where. I looked in the docs for crossmatch, nbpMatching and MASS to see if they talk about parallelizations but they don't.
Edit: The above code should be sufficient for running this on your own PC. Interestingly, parallelization only happened to me under Ubuntu 16.04 and macOS 10.12 but not under Fedora 27.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the dependencies:

```
library(miniCRAN)
tags <- "crossmatch"
dg <- makeDepGraph(tags, enhances = FALSE, suggests = FALSE)
set.seed(1)
plot(dg, legendPosition = c(-1, 1), vertex.size = 20)
```

[image: resulting plot of dependencies]

That is quite a few dependencies. At a first glance, there is no package for R level parallelization there. That leaves the possibility of packages using parallelization via compiled code. One such package is data.table (there might be others), try if using `setDTthreads(1)` turns off parallelization.

Of course, you might also have R linked to an optimized BLAS. If that's the case, the parallelization most likely happens there during matrix algebra.

**Update:**

@Dirk Eddelbuettel [just pointed out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40451820#40451820) that packages [RhpcBLASctl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RhpcBLASctl/index.html) and [OpenMPController](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenMPController/index.html) allow controlling the number of cores used by the BLAS or OpenMP.

**Edit by kartoffelsalat**:

The following worked for the issue in the question under Ubuntu 16.04. It did not work under macOS (neither did the package `OpenMPController`).

```
library(RhpcBLASctl)
blas_set_num_threads(3)
```

Comment: Oh, cool, thanks for this interesting graph! Apparently, data.table is not the cause of my issue because it reports the following when I load it (on a mac this time): "This installation of data.table has not detected OpenMP support. It should still work but in single-threaded mode."
How can I find out whether R is linked to an optimized BLAS and is there a way to provide a maximum number of threads for BLAS then?

Comment: How did you install R? Is it CRAN R? I take it you have not linked it to an optimized BLAS yourself.

Comment: On the mac I've installed it with homebrew. On other machines (ubuntu 16.04, fedora 27) it's coming from the default distribution's software repository. Isn't there a command within R to check if its a linked version?

Comment: `extSoftVersion()`?

Comment: @kartoffelsalat See my update. That should probably enable you to solve this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try. I'm on the move right now, so I'll report tomorrow.